# i‎. ‎$B(X)=C(X)$ ii‎. ‎$C_{0}(X)=C(X)$ iii‎. ‎$C_{0}(X)=C_{c}(X)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

‎Explain‎, ‎when we have the following equalities‎ :

‎
‎i‎. ‎$B(X)=C(X)$.

ii‎. ‎$C_{0}(X)=C(X)$.

iii‎. ‎$C_{0}(X)=C_{c}(X)$.

Where:

‎$B(X)=\{f:X\to \mathbb C \mathrel| f \text{ is bounded}\}$,

$C(X)=\{f\in B(X) \mathrel| f \text{ is continuous}\}$,

‎$C_0(X)=\{f\in C(X) \mathrel| f \text{ vanishes at infinity}\}$, and

‎$C_c(X)=\{f\in C(X) \mathrel| f \text{ has compact support}\}$.

Comment: Normally $C(X)$ denotes the set of *all* continuous functions on $X$, not just the bounded continuous functions (which I would write as $BC(X)$ or $C_b(X)$). Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i.: If $C(X) = \{ f \in B(X) \mid f \text{ continuous} \} $ then of course $C(X) \subseteq B(X)$ by definition.

The question becomes slightly more interesting if you let $C(X) = \{f:X \to \mathbb C \mid f \text{ continuous}\}$. Let $f \in C(X)$. Then $f$ is bounded if $X$ is compact. Hence for compact $X$, $C(X) \subseteq B(X)$.

I think the other direction, $B(X) \subseteq C(X)$, only holds in a discrete space (where every function is continuous). Otherwise you will always be able to find $f$ bounded but not continuous. (A characteristic function will do, for example).

ii.: By definition, $C_0 \subseteq C$. When is it true that $C(X) \subseteq C_0 (X)$? Unfortunately, $f(x) = 1$ is continuous for every possible topology you can put on $X$.

iii.: Of course, $C_c \subseteq C_0$. When is $C_0 \subseteq C_c$? It's not looking good at first glance: The map $f(x) = \frac{1}{1 + |x|}$ vanishes at infinity and does not have compact support (if you picked $X= \mathbb R$). But wait: if $X$ is compact $f: X \to \mathbb C$ will of course have compact support. Hence again, as in i., if $X$ is compact then $C_0 (X) = C_c (X)$.